# Управление обновлением данных в google sheet (IMPORTRANGE)

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Такой вопрос: можно ли контролировать обновление данных из формул? (Конкретно интересует формула IMPORTRANGE.)

В чем проблема.

Есть таблица (BASE) на 20 тыс. заполненных ячеек с формулой IMPORTRANGE, которая привязана к 10 другим таблицам с данными. После обновления данных в других таблицах обновление на главной странице с 20к ячейками происходит очень медленно либо зависает совсем. В результате приходится вручную обновлять страницу несколько раз, пока подхватятся все нужные значения.
Было бы гораздо удобнее, если бы была возможность пересчитывать формулы ячеек по команде (нажатием кнопки), а не автоматически.
Т.е. сначала внести все необходимые изменения в подключенных таблицах, а затем в таблице BASE нажать кнопку, чтобы оно пересчитало все формулы.
На данный момент пересчет происходит в фоновом режиме, и данные обновляются фрагментарно, т.е. одна дополнительная таблица может обновиться быстрее, другая медленнее, третья вообще не обновляется, и необходимо опять нажать F5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, вы не можете этого сделать. Если у вас такое большое количество данных, то возможно, пора использовать базу данных?

В Таблицах есть настройки перерасчета, но для ваших задач они не подойдут.

Выходом из ситуации может быть скрипт на [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/), который будет копировать данные согласно определенному сценарию. Вам не удастся, скорей всего, увеличить время работы, но позволит избежать лишних обновлений страницы.

Не зная сценария тяжело утверждать, как именно это будет работать, но, для примера, может быть и так:

- Кнопка собрать данные
- Кнопка отправить данные
- Кнопка проверить изменения

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTRANGE не работает быстро. Попробуйте собрать данные в один файл c несколькими листами и использовать QUERY() - запрос - он работает гораздо быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, речь идет о формулах? 
Решение простоватое, но у меня работает.
Поставьте перед IMPORTRANGE условие, например такое =ЕСЛИ(kf!D1=0;"";importrange(...))

а в листе kf в ячейке D1 пишите 0 (как заглушку) или не ноль - тогда формула начнет считать). Можно оформить эту ячейку как кнопку.